# Conflicting types with linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, ansi-c

I am in the middle of creating a program in C and I'm not sure what's causing the error as I'm relatively new to C programming (pointers are scary).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {

   char firstName[100];
   char lastName[100];
   char email[100];
   struct Node * partner;

};

struct Node* head;

void main(void)
{
    GetNewNode("John", "Smith", "john.smith@hotmail.com");

}

struct Node * GetNewNode(char fN[100], char lN[100], char em[100]) {

   struct Node* newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

   strcpy(newNode->firstName, fN);
   strcpy(newNode->lastName, lN);
   strcpy(newNode->email, em);

};
```

I seem to get the error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'GetNewNode'
```

Just looking for some help to clarify what's going on.  Thank you!

Comment: Before the error, did you also get a warning that `GetNewNode` was undeclared, or that it was implicitly declared?

Comment: Yes actually.  "warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetNewNode'

Comment: return is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a prototype before declaring `main`:

```
struct Node * GetNewNode(char fN[100], char lN[100], char em[100]);
```

Or move entirely `GetNewNode` function before `main`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed something that simple.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a declaration/prototype for `GetNewNode()` or define it before `main()`.

In your code as is, you don't provide a prototype for `GetNewNode()`. When the compiler reached the line

```
GetNewNode("John", "Smith", "john.smith@hotmail.com");
```

it doesn't know the signature for `GetNewNode()` and it assumes that it returns `int`. Hence the error, `int` and `struct Node *` pointer are incompatible types.